# How do I simplify this pattern matching logic using C# Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Good morning! Hoping someone can help me out here with some pattern matching.

What I want to do is match a string of numbers against a bunch of text. The only catch is that I DO NOT want to match anything that has more numbers to the left and/or right of the number I'm looking for (letters are fine).

Here is some code that works, but it seems that having three `IsMatch` calls is overkill. Problem is, I can't figure out how to reduce it to just one `IsMatch` call.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    list.Add("cm1312nfi"); // WANT
    list.Add("cm1312");  // WANT
    list.Add("cm1312n"); // WANT
    list.Add("1312");    // WANT
    list.Add("13123456"); // DON'T WANT
    list.Add("56781312"); // DON'T WANT
    list.Add("56781312444"); // DON'T WANT

    list.Add(" cm1312nfi "); // WANT
    list.Add(" cm1312 ");    // WANT
    list.Add("cm1312n ");    // WANT
    list.Add(" 1312");       // WANT
    list.Add(" 13123456");   // DON'T WANT
    list.Add(" 56781312 ");  // DON'T WANT

    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        // Can we reduce this to just one IsMatch() call???
        if (s.Contains("1312") && !(Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b[0-9]+1312[0-9]+\b") || Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b[0-9]+1312\b") || Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b1312[0-9]+\b")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is a match for '1312'", s);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is NOT a match for '1312'", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

~Mr. Spock

Comment: what for `list.Add("13121312")` ? MATCH or NOT?

Comment: No, I would NOT want to match "13121312." The accepted answer below also correctly catches this case. Thanks for helping make sure this is a robust solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookarounds for a single check:

```
@"(?<![0-9])1312(?![0-9])"
```

`(?<![0-9])` makes sure that `1312` doesn't have a digit before it, `(?![0-9])` makes sure there's no digit after `1312`.

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect. I "+1" the other answers below because they also work. I selected this one as the "answer" because it also gets rid of the other Contains() check. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr.Spock You're welcome :) Just realised that `.IsMatch` works just as well ^^;

Comment: one point - the Contains may actually be a performance improvement, in large strings.

Comment: @DaveBish But wouldn't the regex have to be called anyway?

Comment: @Jerry - not if the cheaper Contains() call short-circuits the if

Comment: @DaveBish Ah, then that means that one could still put the `.Contains()` first and then use `.IsMatch()`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the character classes optional matches:

```
if (s.Contains("1312") && !Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b[0-9]*1312[0-9]*\b"))
{
    ....
```

Have a look on the amazing Regexplained: http://tinyurl.com/q62uqr3

Answer (score 1):

To catch invalid patterns use:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b[0-9]*1312[0-9]*\b")
```

Also [0-9] can be replaced with `\d`

Comment: Won't it fail for this test case? - `list.Add("56781312444");`

Comment: No. I don't see any reason it may fail. In fact this Regex is to capture invalid patterns. Do you have any idea? Remember the OP said: "... I DO NOT want to match anything that has more numbers to the left **and/or** right of the number I'm looking for..."

Answer (score 0):

You can select only those letters before, after, or none at all

```
@"\b[a-z|A-Z]*1312[a-z|A-Z]*\b"
```

Comment: `|` is just a regular character in a character class, you probably wanted to write `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: You can do it both ways

Comment: No, you can't. `[a|b]` is the same as `[ab|]` or `(?:a|b|\|)`. It's **not** `[ab]` nor `(?:a|b)`.

Answer (score 0):

For curious minds   - Another approach at solving the above problem?

```
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            var rgx = new Regex("[^0-9]");
            // Remove all characters other than digits
            s=rgx.Replace(s,"");
            // Can we reduce this to just one IsMatch() call???
            if (s.Contains("1312") && CheckMatch(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is a match for '1312'", s);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is NOT a match for '1312'", s);
            }
        }
       private static bool CheckMatch(string s)
       {
            var index = s.IndexOf("1312");
            // Check if no. of characters to the left of '1312' is same as no. of characters to its right
            if(index == s.SubString(index).Length()-4)
               return true;
            return false;
       }
```

Considering not a match for "131213121312".